# Download and evaluate historical OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, statistics, history, osmium, geofabrik

**objective**: I want to download historical OSM data for Germany and check the number of new added *nodes, ways, relations* within a certain time range (01.01.2007 to 01.02.2007). Afterwards I want to count the newly added *nodes, ways, relations* of another time range.

**Initial situation**: I used the Geofabrik download to get historical data for Germany (see germany-internal.osh.pbf, a file that contains the full OSM history for this region for processing with e.g. osmium.)

Then I used osmium in the command line:

**Osmium**: I have added in the command line the corresponding commands

1. **osmium-time-filter** - filter OSM data by time from a history file

--> osmium time-filter /XXX/XXX/Downloads/germany-internal.osh.pbf 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z -o 01012015.osm.pbf

Problem: The file contains the nodes, ways, relations as of 01/01/2007. All data before 01.01.2007 are INCLUDED.

2. **osmium-fileinfo** - show information about an OSM file, option -e

--> osmium fileinfo 01012015.osm.pbf -e

Problem: The command counts all nodes, ways, relations contained in the file but I need only the newly added ones.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve your objective is to use the [Ohsome API](https://docs.ohsome.org/ohsome-api/v1/), it seems to do exactly what you want.